# Multiple notification handlers in Kaa Clients

Tags: java, notifications, kaa

I'm working with Kaa 0.10.0. Everything works fine and I'm able to send notifications and receive events with Kaa clients.
Now I've created a new version(version 3) for my notification schema (Added some more fields). Generated new Java SDK (chosen the modified notification schema there) and I've implemented the new notification listener on the client.
I'm able to send notification version 3 from admin UI and the listener catches it. Now I wants to send a notification of version 2 to the same client.
I can send the notification from admin UI by choosing schema version 2, the notification sent successfully but by client is unable to catch it since there is no listener for version 2 notification.

Is there any way to make my client listen to all notification versions I make on server?
I'm planning to use the version as a 'type' of notification that the server sends to the clients - so the client will have all the notification listeners which will collect the notification sent from server and process accordingly.

If its not possible I'll define a field in the notification schema - say 'type' which specifies the type of action the client needs to do.

Answer (score 0):

Kaa SDK supports only a single Notification schema version at once. The versioning is provided there for purposes of support of previous versions of client(s).

So, yes, you should add some field to the schema in order to differentiate the notification type.